# im getting error in django Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/

Tags: django

code of project named carparts urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('parts.urls')),

]
```

code for my app named parts urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [    
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    path('about', views.about,name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact,name='contact'),
]
```

code for views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
   # return HttpResponse('this is home page')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

index page code output is show in http://127.0.0.1:8000 but my about and contact page shows Page not found (404) . Can any one help me with this code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joint '/' in your both **urls.py** like that:

```
 urlpatterns = [    
        path('', views.index,name='index'),
        path('about/', views.about,name='about'),
        path('contact/', views.contact,name='contact'),
    ]
```

According [Django Design philosophy on Definitive URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#definitive-urls):

> Technically, foo.com/bar and foo.com/bar/ are two different URLs, and
> search-engine robots (and some Web traffic-analyzing tools) would
> treat them as separate pages. Django should make an effort to
> “normalize” URLs so that search-engine robots don’t get confused.